# ruby, unix and here documents

Tags: ruby, unix, heredoc

So I'm wondering how to process here docs in ruby, for example, this is the main loop in my program:

```
begin
    word = gets
    if word.nil?
        next
    end
    command = word.chomp.to_s
    print word
end until (word.eql? "EOI")
```

and I run it by doing `./file <<EOI`

If the user changes what's used as the terminating string, however, then the last line will clearly fail. Is there some global variable that lets me detect what the user has specified as a terminating string? If not, what's the best way to handle `<<EOI`?

Thanks yall.

Sample input:

```
hello

world
EOI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why you don't just loop until `word.nil?` which would also be the case if the user sends `EOF` (`Ctrl-d`)?

```
until (word = gets).nil?
  print word.chomp
end
```